# DataTemplate does not show result of bound children

Tags: xaml, binding

On my MainWindow.xaml page, I have the following code which works (where MyWord is a string)

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding MyWord}" />
```

I'm playing with DataTemplates and trying understand them. So, I want to reference a `DataTemplate` from within my `ContentControl`. The `DataTemplate` should contain a `TextBlock` which binds to my string. I updated my code

```
<ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ViewsTemplate}" />
```

And in my ResourceDictionary I add

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ViewsTemplate">  
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyWord}" />  
</DataTemplate>
```

This produces no text on screen at all. I even tried

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding MyWord}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ViewsTemplate}" />
```

and still no result on screen.

I can't work out why can any one give some advice please.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ContentControl` still needs to have some content bound to it.

```
<ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ViewsTemplate}" Content="{Binding MyWord}" />
```

Would work, but then you'd need to change your data template because it expects to be able to find `MyWord` which of course it won't be able to, so you'd want to use just `{Binding}` instead.

Alternatively, bind the `ContentControl`'s `Content` to `{Binding}` - the current `DataContext` of its parent - and leave the template as it is.

Comment: Thank you Matthew, this is exactly what I needed. Also, a big thank you for giving both approaches, these types of suggestions are typically so valuable and very much appreciated!

Comment: I tend to prefer those answers myself so I try to do that whenever possible. You might want to hit the big green tick mark to accept the answer and keep your acceptance stats nice and high. (Disclaimer: I get more reputation if you do that :))